# Jquery lenght of each element with same class

Tags: jquery

I have different numbers of divs with the class "news-list-view-2-cols". They contain different number of div with class "article". I'm trying to say if the number of "div class article" within a "div class news-list-view-2-cols" greater or equal 2 then addClass "article-last" to the last two divs in parent element.

I'm trying

```
if ($( ".news-list-view-2-cols .article" ).length >= 2) { 
    $( ".news-list-view-2-cols .article").slice(-2).addClass("article-last");
}
```

This works for the last "news-list-view-2-cols" in html code but not for the previous. So I have to find a solution that gives me the number of each (.news-list-view-2-cols .article) length. I try, but without success.

Live example:

```js
if ($( ".news-list-view-2-cols .article" ).length >= 2) { 
    $( ".news-list-view-2-cols .article").slice(-2).addClass("article-last");
}

/*
$( ".news-list-view-2-cols .article" ).each(function() {
    if ( this.length >= 2 ) {
        this.slice(-2).addClass("article-last")
 }
});
*/
```

```css
.news-list-view-2-cols {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.article-last {
    color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
 <div class="news-list-view-2-cols cf">
  <div class="article articletype-0">1</div>
  <div class="article articletype-0">2</div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="news">
 <div class="news-list-view-2-cols cf">
  <div class="article articletype-0">1</div>
  <div class="article articletype-0">2</div>
  <div class="article articletype-0">3</div>
  <div class="article articletype-0">4</div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="news">
 <div class="news-list-view-2-cols cf">
  <div class="article articletype-0">1</div>
  <div class="article articletype-0">2</div>
  <div class="article articletype-0">3</div>
  <div class="article articletype-0">4</div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somaberlin/jcamyo1p/)

Comment: Note that I moved the content of your fiddle *into* your question (as a Stack Snippet). Questions must be answerable without referring to off-site content (even if it's on jsFiddle). The HTML structure was important here, so needed to be *in* the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to slice just the articles set, not the overall set:

```
$( ".news-list-view-2-cols").each(function() {
    var articles = $(this).find(".article");
    if (articles.length >= 2) { 
        articles.slice(-2).addClass("article-last");
    }
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$(".news-list-view-2-cols").each(function() {
  var articles = $(this).find(".article");
  if (articles.length >= 2) {
    articles.slice(-2).addClass("article-last");
  }
});
```

```css
.news-list-view-2-cols {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.article-last {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
  <div class="news-list-view-2-cols cf">
    <div class="article articletype-0">1</div>
    <div class="article articletype-0">2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="news">
  <div class="news-list-view-2-cols cf">
    <div class="article articletype-0">1</div>
    <div class="article articletype-0">2</div>
    <div class="article articletype-0">3</div>
    <div class="article articletype-0">4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="news">
  <div class="news-list-view-2-cols cf">
    <div class="article articletype-0">1</div>
    <div class="article articletype-0">2</div>
    <div class="article articletype-0">3</div>
    <div class="article articletype-0">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```